# Auto Load Office Add-In Outlook

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

Is there a way to have an Office JS Add-in autoload without the user having to click the add-in button in the ribbon toolbar?

For example, we have an add-in that auto adds a BCC email address. We would like the add-in to be able to automatically add the BCC email address w/o having to click the add-in button.

We did this with a VSTO plugin but could not find a way to do this using the new Add-In JS API.

Comment: Currently the feature to auto load office add-in outlook is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 1):

1. A web add-in can add support for [ItemSend event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins) (these add-ins are automatically opened in background, when the user clicks on send button) but have a look at [limitations of ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins#limitations) before taking that route.
2. A web add-in can support [pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) (if the user has pinned the add-in, next time the add-in automatically opens in task pane).

There is no other way to open a web add-in without user interaction.
There is [user voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10085988-allow-app-to-run-in-background-without-user-intera), which is similar to your scenario, you can add your support to that.